# Why my style section is gray using postcss with nuxt 3?

Tags: tailwind-css, postcss, nuxtjs3

I don't know why all the style sections of my project having a gray text. Anything work normally but this make it hard to watch.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0qIQ.png).

My nuxt.config.ts

```
// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  typescript: {
    shim: false,
  },
  modules: [
    [
      "@pinia/nuxt",
      {
        autoImports: ["defineStore"],
      },
    ],
  ],
  css: [
    "~/assets/css/tailwind.css",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css",
  ],
  build: {
    postcss: {
      postcssOptions: require("./postcss.config"),
    },
  },
});
```

My postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    "postcss-import": {},
    "tailwindcss/nesting": "postcss-nesting",
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
    ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? { cssnano: {} } : {}),
  },
};
```

`content` of my tailwind.config

```
  content: [
    "./assets/**/*.{vue,js,css}",
    "./components/**/*.{vue,js}",
    "./layouts/**/*.vue",
    "./pages/**/*.vue",
    "./plugins/**/*.{js,ts}",
    "./nuxt.config.{js,ts}",
    "./app.{vue,ts,js}",
  ],
```

Have anyone encountered this problem before? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I installed extension `language-postcss` and its good